# excel vba: Run-time error '438'

Tags: excel, vba

Using code from the spreadsheet guru to loop through files in a folder and perform a set task on them, seems to be working properly.  Where I may have made a mistake is the set task portion of the code.

Using Excel 2010.

```
sourcewb = ActiveWookbook
sourcefn = ActiveWorkbook.Name
masterwb = ThisWorkbook

masterwb.Activate
lr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").ListRows.Count

If ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(lr, 1).Value = "" Then
    sourcewb.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("IntermidateTbl").DataBodyRange.Copy
    masterwb.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(lr, 1).Select
    Selection.Paste
    newlr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").ListRows.Count
    Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(lr, 8), _
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(newlr, 8)) = "" & sourcefn & ""
Else
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
    sourcewb.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("IntermidateTbl").DataBodyRange.Copy
    masterwb.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(lr + 1, 1).Select
    Selection.Paste
    newlr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").ListRows.Count
    Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(lr + 1, 8), _
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTbl").DataBodyRange(newlr, 8)) = "" & sourcefn & ""
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than a few errors, I'll try to help with a few.

You are trying to set `sourcewb`, which is a `Workbook` object, so you need to change:

```
sourcewb = ActiveWookbook
```

To:

```
Set sourcewb = ActiveWookbook
```

(the same goes for `Set masterwb = ThisWorkbook`).

Next, `masterwb.Activate`, you don't need to `Activate` the workbook, and it's also safer to also set reference to the sheet you want, you can also add the `With` statement, and use something like:

```
With masterwb.Worksheets("SheetName")
    lr = .ListObjects("DataTbl").ListRows.Count ' number of rows in "DataTbl" table
```

You can also set an Object to your `ListObjects`.

```
Dim DataTbl As ListObject
Set DataTbl = masterwb.Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("DataTbl")
```

So later on, you can access it's properties much easier (and "cleaner").

For example:

```
lr = DataTbl.ListRows.Count ' <-- get the rows count of the table
```

and:

```
If DataTbl.DataBodyRange(lr, 1).Value = "" Then
```

---

And so on, you have way too many places where you `Activate` the 2 workbooks, and later use `ActiveSheet` and `Selection`.

If you describe better what you are trying to achieve, we can help you achieve it in a more reliable way.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ShaiRado!  I gave several project leads a file that builds a data table, the "IntermediateTbl", and these files are saved in one folder.  From my master file, I want to open the leads files copy the IntermediateTbl and paste into my DataTbl.  I used you comments to edit my code.  Now I get Run-time error '13': type mismatch.

Comment: type mismatch comes from the line     Set sourcewb = ActiveWookbook